# JSON value in View Model displayed as [object Object] only

Tags: nativescript

This will be a noob question. I am working on my first NativeScript app, a simple GPS tracker. It's only one view. I got the `Location` plugin to work and it outputs location data to the console nicely. It also seems to update the View Model. But when I try to bind it to a `Label` element's text, it only displays [object Object], regardless what I do.

**The view model:**

```
var observableModule = require("data/observable");

function viewModel() {

    return new observableModule.fromObject({
        "locations": [],
        "lastLocation": {
            "latitude": "0",
            "longitude": "0",
            "altitude": 0,
            "horizontalAccuracy": 0,
            "verticalAccuracy": 0,
            "speed": "0",
            "direction": "0",
            "timestamp": new Date().toISOString()
        },
        "lastUpload": "Unknown"
    });

}


module.exports = viewModel;
```

**The view XML:** (just the important part)

```
<Label text="Current location:"/>
<Label text="{{ lastLocation?.latitude }} ; {{ lastLocation?.longitude }}" />

<Label text="Last location update:"/>
<Label text="{{ lastLocation?.timestamp }}" />

<Label text="Last successful upload:"/>
<Label text="{{ lastUpload }}" />
```

**The code:**

```
var frameModule = require("ui/frame");
var viewModel = require("./home-view-model");
var geolocation = require("nativescript-geolocation");
var dialog = require("ui/dialogs");

var viewModel = new viewModel();

function onLoaded(args) {

    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = viewModel;

    var enableLocation = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        geolocation.enableLocationRequest(true)
            .then(
            success => resolve(),
            error => reject(error)
            )
    })

        .then(
        () => {
            watchId = geolocation.watchLocation(
                function (loc) {
                    if (loc) {
                        viewModel.lastLocation = loc;
                        console.log(viewModel.lastLocation.latitude + ' ; ' + viewModel.lastLocation.longitude);
                    }
                },
                function (e) {
                    dialogsModule.alert('Location error: ' + e.message);
                },
                {
                    desiredAccuracy: 3,
                    updateDistance: 0,
                    minimumUpdateTime: 10000
                })
        },

        error => {
            dialogsModule.alert('Location error: ' + e.message);
        }
        )

}

exports.onLoaded = onLoaded;
```

The `console.log` row properly displays the latitude and longitude values. The view displays [object Object], but it displays the `lastUpload` value right. What am I doing wrong in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes, it was a noob question. The solution is that I shouldn't use question marks in the template.

```
<Label text="Current location:"/>
<Label text="{{ lastLocation.latitude }} ; {{ lastLocation.longitude }}" />

<Label text="Last location update:"/>
<Label text="{{ lastLocation.timestamp }}" />
```

Now it works.